# Is there a way to combine two for loops so I don't print duplicate data in Python?

Tags: python

I'm using an API to receive data from two different urls that use two different metrics. When I created my two for loops I started to receive the data I wanted but then I realized that I was getting duplicates of the data and I think it's because I have multiple for loops. I think combining them into one for loop might fix the problem but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

```
for ticket1 in ticket_list1:
    for ticket2 in ticket_list2:
        times = ticket2['reply_time_in_minutes']
        ticket_id = ticket2['ticket_id']
        assignee = ticket1['assignee_id']
        priority = ticket1['priority']
        if ticket1['assignee_id'] != ticket1['requester_id']:
            if times['calendar'] != None:
                if priority != None:
                    print("%s %20s %20s %20s" % (times, ticket_id, 
assignee, priority))
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to  sort ticket_list1 and and ticket_list2 first, and *then* loop once they've been merged.

Comment: I don't think `for ticket1 in ticket_list1 and ticket2 in ticket_list2` is valid (actually, it is (if you already defined `ticket2`), but it's not doing what you think it's doing)

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do with `for`-loop in first line but it is not look correclty. If you want to work create pairs with values from two lists - first values from both list, next second values from both list - then use `for ticket1, ticket2 in zip(ticket_list1, ticket_list2):`. If you want to create all possible pairs then create one `for`-loop` inside another `for`-loop - but without `and` - `for ticket1 in ticket_list1: for ticket2 in ticket_list2:`

Comment: It appears these are lists of dictionaries. The dictionaries have different structures. Apparently the 'requester_id' in one dict is the same as the 'assignee_id' in the other. So they strictly don't contain the same data, but they contain values that correspond. If your test is that those two have to be different you are creating something similar to a  cartesian product (you combine all people with all people except when they are the same). It is more likely that you are looking for overlap (i.e. assignee from one database is requester from another). Please look up minimal example.

Comment: Can you confirm that this is correctly copied in your post `if ticket1['assignee_id'] != ticket1['requester_id']` ? In particular, notice that you compare two fields of the same `ticket1` entry.

Comment: @sal Yes, that line is correctly copied. I only want to focus on tickets given by the requester and some that I have are labeled with the agent's id because they were previously worked on and resubmitted which is why I want data that doesn't have the requester and agent id as the same.

Comment: @בנימין כהן You're right. It's not valid. I pasted the wrong line of code but I've fixed it. That was just one of my attempts to fix the problem but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There several ways to print out the list with no duplicates.

One way is to merge the two lists into a sorted list, and eliminate the duplicates.

Another is to merge the two lists into a Python [set](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sets-in-python/), which - by definition - does not allow duplicates.